# Total War Warhammer - Coop with Vampiric/Chaos factions, Friendly corruption

Tags: warhammer-total-war

Ever since I started playing I have always avoid playing Vampire/Chaos factions because I'll end up causing corruption to my Coop ally resulting in all manners of problem - public order, attrition etc.

A few significant things that makes the game hard:

1. Vampire units suffer attrition in non-vampiric lands even if it belongs to Coop Ally, Coop Ally also suffers attrition in Vampiric lands
2. Vampire building that increase local corruption also causes Vampiric Osmosis that corrupts Ally lands. Some faction such as Dwarves causes reverse effect of Purifying Vampiric land while attempting to keep their own free of corruption.
3. Every character including Heroes and Lords minimally causes 2 points of corruption or purification. Sending an army with multiple Heroes to aid Ally instead Corrupts or Purify their land against them.
4. Chaos corruption is very strong against any means to Purify, resting an army in Ally land ends up corrupting the Province severely.

There are a few other minor problems too - including having Chaos starting in the wastes that have little strategic value to Coop Ally but the above four makes it Very Hard to play Coop so your own Ally will end up working against you.

Is there a way a corrupted faction can play with a non-corrupted faction in Coop without negatively affecting each other? And if there is no way to prevent it completely, is there any means to minimise Friendly damages?

Comment: This can only be solved using mods

Comment: @KevinTheGreat Are there any mods you can recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the absence, I was on a holiday. I looked around and this is a collection of mods I found that might help you with the corruption problems in co-op. The mods are as followed.

NOTE: Both players need to have the same mods installed in order to run the co-op campaign

[Chaos - Vampire](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=735780748)

[Empire - Vampire](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=723892840)

[Dwarf - Vampire](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=723795996)

[Greenskins - Vampire](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=723076290)

Comment: Thanks, at least the most painful attrition is no more though the corruption still spreads.